# At 5000 point I received a new privilege.

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, tag-wikis, privileges

I recently reached 5000 points and I got a message, saying I have a new privilege.

"Approve tag wiki edits"

What does this mean?

Comment: Such a notification should have linked to the write-up in the Help Center, [Privileges - approve tag wiki edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).  If you followed that link, perhaps your Question is about more fundamental topics (What is a tag wiki?  What is a tag wiki edit? What is the approval process for such edits?)

Answer (score 5):

Most information about MSE can be found through the [Help Center](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help), which can be accessed from the navbar at the top of the site:

[image]

The Help Center has a section labeled "Privileges".  Click on the only link in that section to find a [list of privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) which are earned at various levels of XP.  This list is clickable.  Clicking on the link for [5,000 XP](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) gives you a description of what the tag wiki editing powers entail.

From that link:

> #### What are tag wikis?
>
> Tag wikis are a general introduction to a topic defined by that tag. They're a place to consolidate and form a sub-community around a tag. They contain, among other things, frequently asked questions in the tag, top users in the tag, and best recent answers in the tag.
>
> #### Voting on tag wiki edits
>
> All registered users can submit edits for tag wikis. When approving these edits, ensure that:
>
> - All the content is original or attributed properly
> - Wiki excerpts are concise and contain an objective description of the tag
>
> When you approve tag wiki edits the person submitting the edit will gain 2 reputation points.